# JavaME/Symbian: remove on-screen keypad

Tags: java-me, symbian, fullscreen

When I run my app full screen mode (Game Canvas, setFullScreenMode(true)) in Nokia Symbian3 emulator a on-screen keypad appears that covers half of the screen. 
How do I get rid of it to implement my own menu/touch screen events? 
Can I make sure it won't appear on users' screens when they install this app?

I've read I need to put MIDlet-Touch-Support: TRUE in JAD file but I don't see any JAD file yet :S

Using Eclipse, Nokia Symbian3 SDK v0.9 SDK emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse supports adding properties to your JAD file, it may be listed as descriptor. That's where you state which midlets are included in your suite, so if you don't have a JAD file you can't run your midlet.

There is a JAD property for setting the type of on-screen keyboard, but I cannot remember what it is at the moment. Probably "Nokia-On-Screen-Keyboard-type: none" or somthing similar.

Comment: Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: no